# How to use Generic type in Swift2

Tags: swift

I'm not familiar with the generic type in swift and then I try to study and practice but I encountered an error in compiler. take a look addNewType() method in ObjectA class. Does anyone can help me? thanks!

```
class TypeA: NSObject {

    override init() {
        print("typeA")
    }
}

class ObjectA<T: TypeA>: NSObject {

    var type = [T]()

    init(type:T) {
        self.type.append(type)
    }

    func addNewType() {
        let newType = TypeA()
        self.type.append(newType) <-- Cannot invoke "append" with an argument list of type '(TypeA)'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type` is an array of type `T`. That means all elements must be of type `T`. In the `addNewType()` method, you try appending an element of type `TypeA` to the array of type `T`. That is a type mismatch. You can only put `T`s in the array, but you are trying to add a `TypeA`. This causes the error.

If you want to let `TypeA`s be put in the array as well then define it as `var type = [TypeA]()`. Because `T` is defined to be a subclass of `TypeA`, you can then put instances of both `T` and `TypeA` in the array.

Comment: Can I convert TypeA to T?

Comment: You can attempt to cast a given instance of `TypeA` to `T`, but it's not guaranteed to work. The cast will only succeed if the instance is in fact an instance of type `T`.

Comment: To clarify with an example: When ObjectA is instantiated, the generic parameter T could be a subclass of TypeA, e.g. ObjectA<TypeB> (where TypeB is a subclass of TypeA).  You cannot add TypeA to an array of [TypeB]; however, you can add TypeB to an array of [TypeA].